# RxSwift: using rx_refreshing for uirefreshcontrol

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol, rx-swift

I am using the `UIRefreshControl` + `Variable` binding to reload data.

It is working, however, the following feels wrong to me:

1) I know there is a `rx_refreshing` variable in the `RXCocoa` extension, but I am unable to get it to work in this context.

2) I am binding answers (which is a `Variable` of array) twice. Once when I load the view controller and again when the `UIRefreshControl` is refreshing.

3) The parts where I check for whether the `UIRefreshControl` is refreshing or not looks really awkward. It feels like it defeats the purpose of using reactive?

```
...

let answers: Variable<[Answer]> = Variable([])

override func viewDidLoad() {       
  loadAnswers()
     .shareReplay(1)
     .bindTo(answers)
     .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
  setupRx()
}

func loadAnswers() -> Observable<[Answer]> {
  return Network.rxArrayRequest(Spark.Answers)
}  

func setupRx() {
  rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)
    .map { _ in !self.rc.refreshing }
    .filter { $0 == false }
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ in
      return self.loadAnswers()
    }
    .bindTo(answers)
    .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

  rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)
    .map { _ in self.rc.refreshing }
    .filter { $0 == true }
    .subscribeNext { [unowned self] _ in
      self.rc.endRefreshing()
    }
    .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}

...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So first of all, It's **not** actually working.  It just **seems** to be working. In your code, you're actually not waiting for the network request to finish before you call `rc.endRefreshing()`.  Instead, you're just making the network call and then immediately calling `endRefreshing()`.

```
// `rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)` only gets called once,
// when the user pulls down.

rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)       // user pulled down to refresh
  .map { _ in !self.rc.refreshing }     // !true -> false 
  .filter { $0 == false }               // false == false
  .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ in
    return self.loadAnswers()           // request answers
  }
  .bindTo(answers)
  .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)       // user pulled down to refresh
  .map { _ in self.rc.refreshing }      // true -> true
  .filter { $0 == true }                // true == true
  .subscribeNext { [unowned self] _ in
    self.rc.endRefreshing()             // end refreshing
  }
  .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

To address concern `1`, you're right, you can use `rx_refreshing` to turn off refreshing instead of `endRefreshing()`.

To address concern `2`, I don't think the `Variable` is necessary or useful, at least in this example.  You could still use it though.  Also, it's not necessary to `loadAnswers()` in two places.

To address concern `3`, yea, you could be simplifying this a lot and using `Rx` a bit more.

Here's code that would actually work, use `rx_refreshing`, and simplify things a lot:

```
let initial = Observable<Void>.just(())
let refresh = rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged).map { _ in () }
let answers = Observable.of(initial, refresh)
    .merge()
    .flatMapLatest{ _ in self.loadAnswers() }
    .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

answers
    .map { _ in false }
    .bindTo(rc.rx_refreshing)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

// also use `answers` to bind to your data source, etc.
```

Comment: this is awesome - exactly the kind of very practical, simple snippets that is needed! 

i have a few questions regarding your last example: i set up answers as a variable, so i can access its value easily when i need it.

in your case, answers is simply an observable which observes the initial (never changes), and the refresh, which is whenever the value changes.

wouldn't you need to put a filter {$0 == false} so you only refresh when the refreshing value is false?

secondly, i see what you did there - the answers will ONLY be set when the loadAnswer completes.

Comment: No need for a `filter` since `rc.rx_controlEvent(.ValueChanged)` will only emit an event when refreshing begins.

Comment: would you be able to use variable in lieu of obseverable for answers in your example?

Comment: Yea it would simply be doing what you were doing before: using a `bindTo`. You also wouldn't need the `shareReplayLatestWhileConnected` anymore. I don't see the need though.